# Mastermind game not working

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to create an application to play the mastermind game but I've run into a problem and I can't quite figure out what's going wrong. *Every time I run the check to see whether the guessed integers are correct, it either returns a value of 1 or 0 (never 2, 3 or 4)*. Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated. **Note: the lines where it prints (a,b,c,d) and (r,q,h,l) are purely for troubleshooting purposes**

```
import random
dummy = True
a=int(random.random()*10)
b=int(random.random()*10)
c=int(random.random()*10)
d=int(random.random()*10)
print(a,b,c,d)
while dummy == True:
        f=0
        if a == 0 or b ==0 or c == 0 or d == 0:
                #run program again
                dummy = False
        print("Enter your four guesses, separated by commas.")
        guess=input()
        t,v,w,y=guess.split(",")
        print(t,v,w,y)
        r=int(t)
        q=int(v)
        h=int(w)
        l=int(y)
        if r==a:
                f+=1
        elif q==b:
                f+=1
        elif h==c:
                f+=1
        elif l==d:
                f+=1
        print(f)
        if f==4:
                dummy = False
                print("Well done!")
```

Comment: You need independent checks. `elif` is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `elif` which only runs if the previous condition was false (it is an abreviation for "else if"). You likely want separate `if`s

```
    if r==a:
            f+=1
    if q==b:
            f+=1
    if h==c:
            f+=1
    if l==d:
            f+=1
```

Your code stops when it increments and as such cannot get bigger than one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're using `elif`. As soon as one one of the conditions is true, it skips the others. Change your `elif`s to `if`s if you want all the checks to run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use if instead elif.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have to replace the elif with if since if the if statements i true,it wont run the rest elifs:

```
import random
dummy = True
a=int(random.random()*10)
b=int(random.random()*10)
c=int(random.random()*10)
d=int(random.random()*10)
print(a,b,c,d)
while dummy == True:
        f=0
        if a == 0 or b ==0 or c == 0 or d == 0:
                #run program again
                dummy = False
        print("Enter your four guesses, separated by commas.")
        guess=input()
        t,v,w,y=guess.split(",")
        print(t,v,w,y)
        r=int(t)
        q=int(v)
        h=int(w)
        l=int(y)
        if r==a:
                f+=1
        if q==b:
                f+=1
        if h==c:
                f+=1
        if l==d:
                f+=1
        print(f)
        if f==4:
                dummy = False
                print("Well done!")
```